# How to allow a remote machine to connect to a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, windows-7, remote-access

I have a mysqld server running on a windows 7 machine. How can I allow a Windows Vista machine to connect to this server?

I know I need to set some permissions using:

```
grant all privileges to username@ip
```

What should the username be? I am not sure with windows.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to first create a user, and then grant it rights...

```
CREATE USER 'someusername'@'someip' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
GRANT ALL ON somedb.* TO 'someusername'@'somip';
```

The username and password is then used in your mysql client on your pc to access the DB:

You can also create a user that can access from anywhere. To do this just use something like this:

```
CREATE USER 'someusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
GRANT ALL ON somedb.* TO 'someusername'@'%';
```

Important: Don't forget to put '' around strings!

Answer (score 0):

'username' is username in MySQL database. Additionally MySQL by default is listening only on loopback interface (127.0.0.1/::1). Change 'bind-address' option in 'my.cnf' configuration file to IP on which you want MySQL to listen for connections. Also remember to allow traffic to port 3306 on your firewall.